# Create Custom Functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm having problems with functions in matlab, I need to do an equalizer that uses 3 filter (high pass, low pass, band pass), I've created three diferent scripts to do this filters, now I want my main program of the equalizer call this 3 scripts, someone knows how to do this? I've serach in the internet but i don't found anything that can help me.

Comment: Make the output of the first function to be the input of the next one...

Comment: Have a look at the Matlab documentation about [functions and scripts](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-and-data-types.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are wanting to pass the filters you have created in as functions to some script that will do the processing.  This is fairly straightforward to do by passing in a function handle as an argument.  If, for example, you have a function called high_pass_filter (written in a file high_pass_filter.m), then you can pass it in as an argument to a function using something like:

```
do_processing(@high_pass_filter, arguments);
```

In the function do_processing, it has as its definition something like

```
function do_processing(filter, arguments)
```

then to apply the filter (i.e. execute high_pass_filter.m), you just need to write

```
filter(arguments_for_filter_function);
```

Then you can call the same processing function for the three different filters.

More on function handles can be found on [this page of the Matlab documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html)